# How to retrieve mail from only a specific person through Outlook using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, extract, attachment, outlook-2007

I got the following code from [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/extract_oulook_2003_NET.aspx?):

```
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folders
    Dim Item As New Object
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim x As Int16

    objOL = New Outlook.Application()
    objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim olfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    olfolder = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
    myItems = olfolder.Items

    Dim i As Integer
    For x = 1 To myItems.Count
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).SenderName)
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).SenderEmailAddress)
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).Subject)
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).Body)
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).to)
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).ReceivedByName)
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).ReceivedOnBehalfOfName)
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).ReplyRecipientNames)
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).SentOnBehalfOfName)
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).CC)
        MessageBox.Show(myItems.Item(x).ReceivedTime)
    Next x
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment

    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachment
        Dim filename As String = "C:\Email Attachments\" + Atmt.FileName
        Atmt.SaveAsFile(filename)
    Next Atmt
```

Now, I got as far as making the default folder the Inbox. What I would like to do is to extend the functionality by retrieving only a specific person's emails and extracting and saving whatever attachments he/she sends. Also, I get the following error when the code reaches the
`Dim Atmt as Outlook.Attachment` part: **Public member 'Attachment' on type 'Object' not found.**  I need this function to retrieve the attachments. I've tried different things, but nothing's worked. Can you please help me?

Comment: The error you are getting because you created Item as new Object and you are not assigning anything to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2

Dim items As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    For x = 1 To myItems.Count
        'Mail from a specific person
        If myItems.Item(x).SenderEmailAddress = "someone@mail.com" Then
            For Each Atmt As Outlook.Attachment In myItems(x).Attachment

```
            'A specific type of file
            If Atmt.FileName.Contains("hello") Then items("hello") = Atmt.FileName
            If Atmt.FileName.Contains("hello1") Then items("hello1") = Atmt.FileName
            If Atmt.FileName.Contains("hello2") Then items("hello2") = Atmt.FileName

            Dim filename As String = "C:\Email Attachments\" + Atmt.FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile(filename)

        Next Atmt
    End If
Next
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In items
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key & ":" & item.Value)
Next
```

Try this code

```
Outlook.Attachment oAttach = myItems.Attachments[0];
```

In VB.Net it will be like

```
Dim oAttach as outlook.Attachment = myItems.Attachments(0);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @vs dev, @ho1: Both of you are right! myItems(x).Attachments worked! Mix of your answers worked. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @hvs dev: How can I retrieve a particular sender's mail and attachments?

Comment: You can always check the SenderEmailAddress property right? Put an if condition in the loop and do the attachment extraction only if the sender name matches the name provided by you.

Comment: @vs dev: I'm a noob when it comes to using Outlook thro' VB/.Net. Thanks for letting me know of this propery. Can you possibly give me the syntax and correct usage? Also, how can I get files only of a particular type from this particular person?

Comment: @vs dev: How can I check if the extracted file's name contains a string, say "Hello", and save the filename in a variable? I should be able to do this for different files which contain different substrings.

Comment: @vs dev: I tried: `For Each Atmt As Outlook.Attachment In myItems(x).Attachments
If Path.GetExtension(Atmt.FileName) = ".xls" Then
        If Atmt.FileName.Contains("Hello") Then
               rds = Atmt.FileName
              End If
              Dim filename As String = "C:\My Files\" + Atmt.FileName
              Atmt.SaveAsFile(filename)
              MsgBox(rds)
       End If
Next Atmt`
All it did was to retrieve only that file which contained Hello and displayed that faithfully in the `msgbox`. If I remove the If condition, it retrieves more files. All I want is for it to retrieve...

Comment: @vs dev: all the files, but to store the different file names in different variables. How can I do this? And, sorry about the formatting, I can't seem to find a nice way of posting code. Sorry! :(

Comment: @vs dev: I hope you understood what I'd written in the code part, because I really don't know how I can format it. :( What I would like to do is this: I will get about 3 files from one person daily. I have to detach and save these files. Which is what the code above does. I have to store these file names in 3 different variables because they will form a part of a query to dump these files in a table. So, how can I save these file names in a variable till the dumping is complete? Also, I need your thoughts. Would this code be robust enough to work on a daily basis, if autorun?

Comment: @vs dev: Thanks for all the help! Working like a charm!

Comment: @vs dev: I could isolate the file names, but when I use it in an OPENROWSET query, as follows: `con = New OleDbConnection("provider=SQLOLEDB;data source=myshore4-pc;initial catalog=Nemmadi;integrated security=SSPI")
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into bank_input_file select *from openrowset('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\Nemmadi Files\'" & items("Target") & "'','select *from [Summary1$]'", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim res As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()` The following error pops up: Incorrect syntax near 'Summary'.

Comment: @vs dev: Even after trying a multitude of permutations and combinations, I was unable to do anything about it. Any help? Thanks!! :)

Comment: @vs dev: Hey.. Here's an addition to the problem. I'm creating a log file of everything and wanted to log a custom message, as "File not found", if the `If Atmt.FileName.Contains("hello") Then items("hello") = Atmt.FileName` condition fails. I put an else statement, but it didn't work. What could be wrong?

Comment: I think you need to modify code like this If Atmt.FileName.Contains("hello") Then {enter_key} items("hello") = Atmt.FileName{enter_key} Else WriteLog(""){enter_key} End If

Comment: @vs dev: I tried that, but its matching the `Else` against the outer 'If' and not the `If` that checks for the name. :(

Comment: @vs dev: `If Path.GetExtension(Atmt.FileName) = ".xls" Then
                        If Atmt.FileName.Contains("Hello1") Then items("File1") = Atmt.FileName
                        If Atmt.FileName.Contains("Hello1") Then items("File2") = Atmt.FileName
                        If Atmt.FileName.Contains("Hello3") Then items("File3") = Atmt.FileName`    Putting an `else` matches with the extension if, and not the inner if. What to do?

Comment: @vs dev: Putting an elseif too, yields the same results.. :(

Answer (score 1):

In the codeproject sample code you're looking at, the attachment bit is supposed to be inside the loop, so:

```
For x = 1 As Integer To myItems.Count
    For Each Atmt As Outlook.Attachment In myItems(x).Attachment
        Dim filename As String = "C:\Email Attachments\" + Atmt.FileName
        Atmt.SaveAsFile(filename)
    Next Atmt
Next
```

Comment: How can I retrieve a particular sender's mail and attachments?